# UIBarButtonItem not released after the deinit get called

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

I have two VCs. Both of them use `setToolbarItems` to assign toolbar buttons programmatically in `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear`.

```
func loadToolbarItems {
    guard !toolbarButtonController.isBuilt else { return }
    setToolbarItems(toolbarButtonController.build(), animated: false)
}
```

The `toolbarButtonController.build()` is just a convenient method for appending `UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)` which doesn't keep any UIView reference. The memory usage keeps increasing as the allocated `UIBarButtonItem`.

[image]

[image]

The VC doesn't have the memory leak problem.
I've tried `UIBarButtonItem.target = nil` and `toolbarItems?.removeAll()` but none of these worked.
How can I release these references?

Comment: If your deinit called; then it is not issue with that class  What is `toolbarButtonController` . looks like shared instance. make sure you are not adding bar button item every time.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Do you mean that there will be 100 `UIBarButtonItem` allocated in memory if I call `setToolbarItems` 10 times with 10 buttons in the same VC? If so, how do I release those buttons?

Comment: @KimiChiu did you get the answer of the question?